# How to select elements with a certain ID

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I apologize if this is a really dumb question but I'm just getting started with CSS. I'm using bootstrap to create a website but I'm trying to figure out how to override some of the Boostrap styles. I read one post that suggested creating an ID called `bootsrap-override`. But when I try to select the ID and the element it never works.

Here is my html

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light" 
id="bootstrap-override">
```

And here is my css

```
#bootstrap-override nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-width: thick;
}
```

Comment: You may need to include !important after those styles:
`#bootstrap-override nav{
border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
border-width: thick; !important
}`

Answer (score 0):

`#bootstrap-override nav {`

Looks like the above selector is not correct, try below instead:

```
nav#bootstrap-override {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way.

```html
<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light" id="bootstrap-override">

<style>
#bootstrap-override{
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-width: thick;
}

/* Or you can do it this way
nav #bootstrap-override{
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-width: thick;
} */
</style>
```